# java - the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat7, deployment-descriptor

I am trying to create a simple web application but I am facing this error :

> HTTP Status 404 - /LatestFMS/index.html type Status report message
>   /LatestFMS/index.html description The requested resource is not
>   available. Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

I have done everything properly , the contents of web.xml are as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>LatestFMS</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And index.html is present in the public folder.

But when I use filter with urlMapping "/*" and I try to print anything , then it prints it but shows the 404 error .i.e the control is reaching the server and even to the filters, but its not going beyond that .i.e to index.html. I am unable to understand what is happening.

And when I dont use the filter and try to access the index.html page using the link "http://localhost:8082/LatestFMS/index.html" then again I it gives the 404 error.

Please help me resolve this !!

Comment: Are you sure Tomcat is running on port 8082? Also what do you see if you try opening http://localhost:8082 ?

Comment: Can you share the application structure? and is your index.html present under WebContent or under WEB-INF?